# Rails App Fails to Load Root Path '/ ' on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm receiving the following message after deploying my Rails application to Heroku **'The page you were looking for doesn't exist'**. It runs on my local host just fine, it's just on Heroku the issue occurs.

I've made sure to run `heroku run rake db:migrate` and set my root in routes.rb to `root 'welcome#index'`

When I run `rake routes` locally I get the following (not the full list)

```
    Prefix Verb          URI Pattern         Controller#Action                                                                       
         root GET     /                  welcome#index                                                                              
welcome_index GET    /welcome(.:format)  welcome#index
```

The root path is noticeable missing when I run `heroku run rake routes`

```
Prefix Verb                        URI Pattern                                                                          Controller#Action                                                                  
rails_service_blob        GET  /rails/active_storage/blobs/:signed_id/*filename(.:format)                               active_storage/blobs#show
rails_blob_representation GET  /rails/active_storage/representations/:signed_blob_id/:variation_key/*filename(.:format) active_storage/representations#show
```

Heroku Logs show the following:
`2020-06-25T01:46:58.550276+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2020-06-25T01:46:58.550205 #4] FATAL -- : [b01338d3-12f9-486c-8b05-0f7e525d01ba] ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/"):`

I've also deleted my Heroku application and started from scratch. I just can't seem to figure out why my root path is not being recognized.

adding Routes.rb file content

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'welcome#index'
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

end
```

Comment: Can you post your actual routes file?

Comment: @RockwellRice just added it

Comment: something is off about this app,  is the github repo public by any chance?

Comment: Did you commit the changes to your `routes.rb` file and push the changes to heroku?